# Count Unique ID per Attribute per Variable

Tags: r

My objective is to count the frequency of the top attributes for each variable in a dataframe, but instead of only counting the frequency of the attribute itself, I'd like to count by unique ids for the selected attribute.

If I was interested in just counting the frequency of the top attributes for each variable, I can use the following code:

```
lapply(df, function(attribute){
j <- as.data.frame(sort(table(attribute), decreasing=TRUE)[1:10])
})
```

I'd like to exactly the above, but ensuring that each id is unique. I cannot filter the dataframe because it is on the attribute level and I'd loose data for certain attributes/variables.

```
example input data for testing:
      id  v1  v2   v3  v4
    1  7   1   A  100  98 
    2  7   2   A   98  97
    3  8   1   C   50  80
    4  8   1   C   78  75
    5  8   1   C   50  62
    6  9   3   C   75  75
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate top frequency for each variable in each `id` ? So top 10 attributes for `id = 7` and in `v1`, then same for `v2` and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Get the data in long format, count occurrence of each value for `id` in every column and keep only top 10 values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(-id, as.character)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  count(id, name, value) %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 10)
```

To count unique id's for each value in the column you can try :

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(-id, as.character)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -id) %>%
  group_by(name, value) %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(id))
```

Comment: This is very close, but I think you are counting for id, name and value. I basically want your output and then group by name and value and return the counts for each. This would ensure all counts for the name and value would have unique ids

Comment: Do you mean adding `%>% count(name, value)` to the above output? I am not sure if I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: I want to count the unique ids, grouping by name and value. The above code counts the frequency of the same id on a name and value level. I used the code 'df2 <- ddply(df, .(df$name, df$value), nrow)', but this doesn't work when I use mapply to apply it to a list of dataframes

Comment: @AustinGilbert Updated answer might help.